# MOSFET symbol with line through it

Tags: schematics, nmos

What connections (e.g. between gate, drain, source, body, and surrounding circuit) are implied by this MOSFET symbol with a line through it (M3)? For comparison, here is another NMOS transistor from the same paper without a line through it (M4).

[image: NMOS with line through it]
[image: Normal NMOS schematic]

Comment: IS there another one to the right of it. It is common to draw gates joined like that. (Or bases for BJTs)

Comment: M4 is to the right of M3 with a resistor in between. To the left of M3 is a capacitor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Through-routed gates

It's common in IC schematics to route a connection *through* the base/gate of a transistor -- that means "connect to this base/gate and keep going" in a compact and efficient way, vs. having to tap off a wire and route around the transistor symbol.  No body connections are implied by the through-routing, by the way.